# How to reduce intensity of air flow from my window AC unit

Tags: home, bedroom, air, office, fan

How to reduce intensity of air flow from my window AC unit in Asia during a curfew / in condo lockdown?

I emphasize again:

- Currently in Asia (so do not think US style)
- Currently in Curfew/ Lockdown

I’ve decreased the blower / fan setting to the lowest and it still is too much. No matter lowest setting & directing the movable vents up/ down, left right the intensity of air flow in the room is too much (can feel direct air at other end of room opposite to AC)

I prefer the cooling functionality, but this blower is too much.

For now I can apply a temporary outer hack, but please feel free to share & add possible inner hack. A dual pronged approach answer would be best.

Note:

I won’t be able to remove the plastic a/c cover panel right now but in few weeks when maintenance guys come maybe something could be inserted in front of main blower vents, in between unit and its front panel (once I test & see how the temporary reductions intensity works out & has to be fine tuned).

I’m wondering what different ways & ideas this could be done.

- Put some kind of fabric / cloth / sheet / towel / pillow / paper / something solid like cardboard?

  - **Each being different in air flow directional/ redirecting, air flow diffusing properties once applied**
- Different ways it could be adhered there / kept up / tied?
- Would prefer to avoid sticky stuff or nails

But I do have right away as shown in pics:

- Masking tape & Velcro cable ties (bottom Left)
- Curtain rod (top right)
- Lighting shelf (top left)
- Main blower vents

Sharing picture of A/C unit, blower & surroundings:

[image: Main pic]
[image: close up]
[image: vents close up]

Answer (score 2):

My hack is to obtain a length of bamboo or similar and tape it to the curtain rod at one end, and to the shelf at the other end. Shown as the orange line in this picture.

[image]

Then hang some fabric from the pole, and direct the fan vent right at it. This should prevent the air from being blown to the other end of the room. As long as you don't completely block off the area, cool air should still be able to circulate through the room by convection, but without the direct blast.

It may not be possible to rest the bamboo *on top of* the curtain pole without preventing the window curtain from fully closing (left picture). But you could use several loops of tape to secure the bamboo to the curtain pole (right picture).

[image]

Comment: Caution: do not obstruct the vents directly, which might cause the a/c unit to overheat and/or malfunction.